# How do I set-up multiple variables when given a nested dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I saw that you can write this:
`score, name = (1500, 'Bill')`
Then `print(score)` and you get `1500` etc.

How do I do the same here?
`shop = {'melee': ('sword', 'axe', 'mace'), 'ranged':('bow', 'crossbow')}`

I've tried using
`{wpn_type: (wpn)} = shop`

I want to be able to write:
`wpn_type`
and get
`('melee', 'ranged')`
and
`wpn`
to get
`(('sword','axe','mace'),('bow','crossbow'))`
or something of the like. Thanks!

Comment: What you're seeing is called tuple unpacking & the name should tell you that it only works with tuples not dictionaries. You'll need to get the keys & values from the dictionary manually.

Comment: It's a Dictionary so you can unpack it, because it's of key and value pairs

Answer (score 0):

One way I see this being possible is by accessing the dictionaries keys and values, adding them to a tuple, and then unpacking it.

```
shop = {'melee': ('sword', 'axe', 'mace'), 'ranged':('bow', 'crossbow')} 
k,tup = (tuple(shop.keys()),tuple(shop.values()))
print(k)
print(tup)
```

outputs

```
('melee', 'ranged')
(('sword', 'axe', 'mace'), ('bow', 'crossbow'))
```

or use `.items()`

```
shop = {'melee': ('sword', 'axe', 'mace'), 'ranged':('bow', 'crossbow')} 
ke = []
val = []
for k,v in shop.items():
    ke.append(k)
    val.append(v)
print(ke,val)
```

output

```
['melee', 'ranged'] 
[('sword', 'axe', 'mace'), ('bow', 'crossbow')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, you can use `zip` to "unzip" items as well.

```
wpn_type, wpn = zip(*shop.items())
```

---

**How did that work?**

If you look at this piece by piece:

```
>>> list(shop.items())
[('melee', ('sword', 'axe', 'mace')), ('ranged', ('bow', 'crossbow'))]
```

Note that the first element of each tuple is what you want to collect in `wpn_type`, and the second element in `wpn`.

You can unpack the iterable to provide `zip` with each tuple as separate arguments. It then returns a sequence consisting of:

1. A tuple of the arguments' first elements
2. A tuple of the arguments' second elements.

Voila!